# Excel VBA Time card - Error with clock in clock out function

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a basic time card for work that can be run on excel daily for multiple users.  I'm running into two issues that I am looking for help on.

1. The VBA I've created seems to need a "filler" in-between blank spaces in order to allow it to work. IE Blank, Filler Data, Blank, Filler Data, etc. Otherwise, it will not initialize upon running the macro button.  Is there a better way to do this or an error in my code causing this?
2. I'm wondering if this code can also be modified to allow for a specific range instead of H1 through H21.  I'd like to move the actual timecard for easier printing.

---

```
Sub ClockInClockOut()

'This code looks for empty cells in the range H1:H21
'and allows the user to clock-in and clock-out.
'It looks at cells one by one and enters time stamp.

    Dim sourceCol As Integer, rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
    Dim currentRowValue As String

    sourceCol = 8 'column H has a value of 8
    rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row

    'for every row, find the first blank cell and select it
    For currentRow = 1 To rowCount
        currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Value
        If IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "" Then
            Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Select
            Exit For

        End If

    Next

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=NOW()"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-en-US]mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM;@"
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: from your code it looks like you want to find the first empty cel in H1:H21 and fill it with current timestamp. If thats all you want to do, the code runs fine

Comment: the only issue i see is when the last row in col H is not 21. your code will basically look for an empty cell between 1 and last non-empty cell.

Comment: Hi nc23, I'm wondering though if I can change the sourceColumn and instead use a range.  The code works, but not as I would have intended.  I used that source as a place holder for now.  As well, I'd like to get rid of the need for something in-between the blank cells...I'm unsure why that is being needed. Thanks!

Comment: you can create a named range for your sourcecolumn and use it in the code. see my answer. I still don't understand where do you need to have a filler. May be a screenshot would help

Comment: what's your actual goal? you may post some "before" and "after" scenarios

Answer (score 0):

if you are specifically looking at the range H1:H21, below code may work

```
Sub ClockInClockOut2()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("myTimestamps")
        If IsEmpty(c) Or c.Value = "" Then
            With c
                .Value = Now()
                .NumberFormat = "[$-en-US]mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM;@"
                Exit For
            End With
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```